# I am unable to send data from AngularJS to Spring MVC controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

How to pass the form values to the Angular script and, from script to Spring MVC controller. Below I have written code where form data is unable to send the controller

### Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('formSubmit', []);

app.controller('FormSubmitController',[ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.list = [];
        $scope.headerText = 'AngularJS Post Form Spring MVC example: Submit below form';
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.submit = function() {

             var formData = {
                     "name" : $scope.name,
                     "salary" : $scope.salary,
                     "designation" : $scope.designation,
             };                                          

             var response = $http.post('submitmock',{ Emp: formData}); //passing Emp
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list.push(data);
                });         


                response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("Exception details: " + JSON.stringify({
                        data: $scope.formData //used formData model here
                    }));
                });

            //Empty list data after process
            $scope.list = [];

        };
    }]);
```

### Spring MVC controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "submitmock", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Emp getMock(@RequestBody Emp Emp)  
{   
    serviceInD.savedata(Emp);
    return Emp;
}
```

Comment: please check the console and share the error

Comment: @brk  angular.js:8553 POST http://localhost:8081/Demo/submitmock 415 ()

Comment: Whats the media type you are using/ server expected. HTTP 415 is because of unsupported media type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to allow the cross origin in your spring MVC

like that :

```
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "submitmock", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Emp getMock(@RequestBody Emp Emp)  
{   
    serviceInD.savedata(Emp);
    return Emp;
}
```

You can refer to the spring guide : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors-controller

Comment: You need to import the annotation with 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

Comment: i dont want to use rest, simple mvc angularjs hibernate i want to use

Comment: this is not about a REST application Spring when have a request from another source will deny it by default the crossorigin is there to allow the communication if you don't do it the request will be stopped before and never reach your controller

Answer (score 0):

You will need to indicate the type of data you send to your controller in your http post.
You can specify the type with header in your request :

`var response = $http.post('submitmock', { Emp: formData}, {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});`

Comment: Are your using spring mvc as it, without spring boot ? You maybe missing Jackson library in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

Your formData is already body do not need to map with Emp. Try replacing the following code in your script file

```
var response = $http.post('submitmock', formData); //passing Emp
                response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.list.push(data);
                });
```

Comment: i want map it because i want to use the same pojo type in it so i used it